# Function signature with no function body

Tags: go

When viewing the source for the [`math.Ceil`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/math/floor.go?s=725:753#L26) method, I found this syntax where there's an exported function signature with no body, and a non-exported version of the same signature that includes the implementation:

```
// Ceil returns the least integer value greater than or equal to x.
//
// Special cases are:
//  Ceil(±0) = ±0
//  Ceil(±Inf) = ±Inf
//  Ceil(NaN) = NaN
func Ceil(x float64) float64

func ceil(x float64) float64 {
    return -Floor(-x)
}
```

I assume this is some syntax which allows you to easily export a local function. Is that correct? And why would one do this instead of just having a single exported function and using it within the package?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [Go language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations).

> A function declaration may omit the body. Such a declaration provides the signature for a function implemented outside Go, such as an assembly routine.

In this case, the `Ceil` function is implemented by an architecture specific assembly file for 386 in `floor_386.s`. Both the amd64 and arm architectures each have an assembly file that implements `Ceil()` as well, but those assembly files are just glue to call the unexported `ceil()` function.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks much!