# how to get g in golang MPG model

Tags: go, runtime

I'm reading some runtime of code of golang(go1.6.2 linux/amd64), Could someone help me to understand the underlying mechanism of getg() function in runtime/stubs.go file?

```
// getg returns the pointer to the current g.
// The compiler rewrites calls to this function into instructions
// that fetch the g directly (from TLS or from the dedicated register).
func getg() *g
```

how do the getg() function operate here? What is the body of this function?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the code you're reviewing?  Perhaps it's Cgo?

Answer (score 6):

See [Function signature with no function body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189606/function-signature-with-no-function-body), and the specification for [Function Declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations).

In the case of `runtime.getg` the code is directly emitted by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot ! But how to get more details about the execution of this function when it is processed by compiler?

Answer (score 2):

It's not being executed—exactly because, as stated in the comment

> The compiler rewrites calls to this function into instructions
>   that fetch the `g` directly (from TLS or from the dedicated register).

As you can obtain yourself via something like

```
grep -rFw getg /usr/share/go-1.7/src/
```

the code which is emitted when the compiler sees a call to `runtime.getg()`
is architecture-dependent and is located in the files

```
{src}/src/cmd/compile/internal/{arch}/ggen.go
```

(for Go 1.7)—where `{src}` is the source directory of your Go code
and `{arch}` is an architecture-specific directory.

Say, for `amd64`, it's `{src}/cmd/compile/internal/amd64/ggen.go`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helps me a lot !